# Multiple foreign keys in one column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I am trying to create a database for a homepage for dogs.
I use mysql and php. Every dog has a dog_id (PRIMARY KEY), which it can be identified by.
Now, I would like to be able to link a dog to its siblings. The problem here is that the number of siblings might be anywhere between 0 to let's say 25. Therefore, I am unsure how to do this.
Here is **my 1st attempt**

```
TABLE `dogs` (
    `dog_id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incremented PRIMARY KEY',
    `dog_sibling1` INT(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL COMMENT 'FOREIGN KEY dog_id of the dog\'s 1st sibling',
    `dog_sibling2` INT(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL COMMENT 'FOREIGN KEY dog_id of the dog\'s 2nd sibling',
     and so on....
     );
```

The problem I see here is that worst case I end up with 25 columns of NULL and most of the time with a lot of NULL columns.
**My 2nd attempt**

```
TABLE `dogs` (
        `dog_id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incremented PRIMARY KEY',
        `dog_sibling_ids` INT(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL COMMENT 'FOREIGN KEY dog_ids of the dog\'s siblings',
         );
```

Like this I would just have one column but I do not know if it is even possible to save an array of foreign keys in one column? And I also would not be sure how to deal with this in php then.
Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: You should create a dog_sibling table.

Comment: So for each dog I should create an own table just with siblings in it? Could you please elaborate a little.. I am really new to this!

Comment: No, you have one table named 'dog' and another table named 'dog_sibling' it would contain (dog_id, sibling_dog_id). When a dog has a sibling, you just add the key of both dogs to that table.

Comment: That is utterly genius!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would likely be to have a second table that 'groups' the siblings together.

```
CREATE TABLE dog_siblings (
   sibling_group_id INTEGER,
   dog_id integer
);
```

This way, if dog_ids 5-9 are all related, they just need to share a common sibling_group_id in the new table, and you can find all dogs related using a query similar to the following

```
SELECT ds2.dog_id
FROM dogs d
    INNER JOIN dog_siblings ds
        ON d.dog_id = ds.dog_id AND d.dog_id = 1
    INNER JOIN dog_siblings ds2 
        ON ds.sibling_group_id = ds2.sibling_group_id
```

And that'll give you all dogs who are siblings of the dog with id 1 (including dog 1)

(edit: stupid inability to comment, the comments on the op appeared while i was crafting this, honest)

Comment: You need `PRIMARY KEY (sibling_group_id, dog_id), INDEX(dog_id)`

Answer (score 1):

I would make a solution similar to the one you suggest in your question: create one table called `siblings` and reference it from `dogs` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `siblings` (
    `siblings_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE `dogs` (
    `dog_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    `dog_sibling_id` INTEGER REFERENCES `siblings`
);
```

I wouldn't put any reference from the `siblings` table to the `dogs` table as it is clearly a one-to-many relationship (one siblings group can have many dogs but a dog can only belong to one siblings group). What about the dogs that have no siblings? You can either create a siblings group for those dogs also or just leave `dog_sibling_id` as `NULL`.

The previous works if you want to know the siblings of one litter (group of baby dogs born at the same time). If you need to track the siblings between different litters add the `mother` and `father` references:

```
CREATE TABLE `litters` (
    `litter_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    `mother_id` INTEGER REFERENCES `dogs`,
    `father_id` INTEGER REFERENCES `dogs`
);

CREATE TABLE `dogs` (
    `dog_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    `dog_litter_id` INTEGER REFERENCES `litters`
);
```

You could also just add the `mother` and `father` columns to the `dogs` table and drop the `litters` table (in which case the litter specific information would be lost).

Comment: You are describing litters, not siblings. It's extremely likely for a stud to sire multiple litters with multiple bitches, and likewise for a bitch to have litters sired by different studs.  Consider studs A and B, and bitches C, D and E.

A breeds with C & D, B breeds with D & E. You now have littlers AC, AD and BD, BE.  AC & AD are paternal siblings, so are BD and BE. AD and BD are maternal siblings, so AD, BD are siblings, as are AD, AC, but not AC, BD. So yeah, many to many.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Expanded answer.